# estimate_gas() errors with: PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py

I am having a problem estimating the gas for a swap, this is the code in python using web3.py

I am testing this in Binance Smart Chain, and getting this error on estimate_gas():

```
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT
```

Regardless of amountOutMin I indicate and regardless of out token (DAI, USDC, CAKE, etc). In this script the input is BNB (not WBNB, but BNB) and out token is DAI.

```py
import math
import time
import codecs
import datetime
from web3.gas_strategies.time_based import fast_gas_price_strategy
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
from eth_keys import keys
from web3 import Web3

# Define web3 provider
provider_url = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(provider_url))
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
web3.eth.set_gas_price_strategy(fast_gas_price_strategy)
wallet_address = '<WALLET_ADDRESS>'
wallet_secret = '<WALLET_SECRET>'

pancake_router_address = '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e'

pancake_router_abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]"}
        ],
        "name": "getAmountsOut",
        "outputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]"}
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]"},
            {"internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address"},
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256"}
        ],
        "name": "swapExactETHForTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]"}
        ],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    }, {
        "inputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]"},
            {"internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address"},
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256"}
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]"},
            {"internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address"},
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256"}
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]"}
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]"},
            {"internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address"},
            {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256"}
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForETH",
        "outputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]"}
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
]
token_abi = [
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": False,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "guy",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "wad",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
]

pancake_router_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.to_checksum_address(pancake_router_address),
                                            abi=pancake_router_abi)

bnb_address = '0xf9A2462Daf87ED43D5449cb4B9f6E4213F980271'  # anyBNB
wbnb_address = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'
dai_address = '0x1af3f329e8be154074d8769d1ffa4ee058b1dbc3'

in_token = bnb_address
out_token = dai_address



in_quantity = 0.03
gas_price = web3.eth.gas_price
max_gas_swap_usd = 5
max_slippage = 0.03  # 3%
deadline_tolerance = 300


def get_public_key_from_private(pv_key):
    decoder = codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")
    private_key_bytes = decoder(codecs.encode("{}".format(pv_key)))
    pkv = keys.PrivateKey(private_key_bytes[0])
    return pkv.public_key.to_checksum_address()


if wallet_address == '':
    wallet_address = get_public_key_from_private(wallet_secret)

bnb_price_usd = 310
in_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.to_checksum_address(in_token), abi=token_abi)
in_decimals = in_contract.functions.decimals().call()

# Calculated min amount of tokens acceptable
in_quantity_wei = int(in_quantity * 10 ** in_decimals)

# If input token is BNB address then the route must indicate WBNB as it is the native token in BSC
route = [
    Web3.to_checksum_address(wbnb_address),
    Web3.to_checksum_address(out_token)
]

# https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/library#getamountout
_, min_out_quantity_wei = pancake_router_contract.functions.getAmountsOut(int(in_quantity_wei), route).call()
deadline = int(datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp() + deadline_tolerance)
# adjust per slippage
min_out_quantity_wei = int((1 - max_slippage) * min_out_quantity_wei)

# Estimate gas price for swap
# https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexactethfortokens
tx = pancake_router_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(min_out_quantity_wei, route, wallet_address, deadline)
estimated_gas_count = tx.estimate_gas({
            'from': wallet_address
})
# add 10% more gas just in case
swap_gas = math.ceil(estimated_gas_count + (0.10 * estimated_gas_count))
swap_gas_bnb = web3.from_wei(swap_gas, 'ether')
swap_gas_usd = float(swap_gas_bnb) * bnb_price_usd

if swap_gas_usd >= max_gas_swap_usd:
    raise ValueError(f'We need {swap_gas_usd} to approve which exceeds the maximum')

tx = pancake_router_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(min_out_quantity_wei, route, wallet_address,
                                                             deadline).buildTransaction(
    {
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address),
        'to': pancake_router_address,
        'gas': swap_gas,
        'gasPrice': gas_price,
    }
)

# sign the transaction
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, wallet_secret)

# send transaction
tx = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

print("HASH: ", Web3.to_hex(tx))
start = time.time()
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx)
print(f'Done waiting took {time.time() - start}')
```

I have the code that does the reverse using swapExactTokensForETH and it works smoothly somehow.